# Loading data into Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, sqoop, flume

I am trying to find out what are the right answers for these 2 questions, both dealing with loading data to your Hadoop that I found on the web as part of my studies the materials and case studies for Hadoop development.

*The first question is:*

**You have user profile records in your OLPT database, that you want to join with web logs you have already ingested into the Hadoop file system. How will you obtain these user records?**

A. HDFS command

B. Pig LOAD command

C. Sqoop import

D. Hive LOAD DATA command

E. Ingest with Flume agents

F. Ingest with Hadoop Streaming

I found different resources indicating of different answers as the correct answers (B / C)

*The second question is:*

**You want to understand more about how users browse your public website, such as which pages they visit prior to placing an order. You have a farm of 200 web servers hosting your website. How will you gather this data for your analysis?**

A. Ingest the server web logs into HDFS using Flume.

B. Write a MapReduce job, with the web servers for mappers, and the Hadoop cluster nodes for reduces.

C. Import all users’ clicks from your OLTP databases into Hadoop, using Sqoop.

D. Channel these clickstreams inot Hadoop using Hadoop Streaming.

E. Sample the weblogs from the web servers, copying them into Hadoop using curl.

Here the suggested answers were either A or B, depending on the source...

**EDIT:**

This is an explanation to the answer B that I found that made me think twice about the answer:

*Hadoop MapReduce for Parsing Weblogs Here are the steps for parsing a log file using Hadoop MapReduce:*

Load log files into the HDFS location using this Hadoop command: hadoop fs -put

The Opencsv2.3.jar framework is used for parsing log records.

Below is the Mapper program for parsing the log file from the HDFS location.

```
public static class ParseMapper     
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable,Text > {

   private Text word = new Text();

   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
       throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      CSVParser parse = new CSVParser(' ','\"');  
      String sp[]=parse.parseLine(value.toString()); 
      int spSize=sp.length;    
      StringBuffer rec= new StringBuffer();

      for(int i=0;i<spSize;i++){    
         rec.append(sp[i]);    

         if(i!=(spSize-1))    
          rec.append(",");    
      }    
   word.set(rec.toString());    
   context.write(NullWritable.get(), word);   
   }    
}
```

**<\EDIT>**

Will be thrilled to get absolute answers for those question, Gday, D.

Comment: I too have addressed some fake answers given by some of the sources.Dont depend on the answers they provide.http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/09/what-do-you-think-of-these-three.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1:
>
> Answer: C
>
> Explanation:
>     You need to join User profile records and weblogs. Weblogs is
>   already ingested into HDFS.So inorder to join weblogs with user
>   profile,we need to bring user profile also into HDFS.User profile is
>   residing in OLPT database so to import that to HDFS we need the help
>   of **SQOOP**.

---

> Question 2:
>
> Answer: A
>
> Explanation:
>    You need to gather the information of web servers hosting your
>   website. And you have a farm of 200 web servers hosting your
>   website.so to bring them to HDFS you need the help of **FLUME**.

Comment: Thank you. I was also Thinking Flume naturally, till I encountered edited explanation to answer B. Please look at my edit of the question where I've put an example that made me think twice and please tell me if it changes anything...

Comment: @theexplorer:they might be thinking that the user record may be in there hands. but the user data is residing in OLTP database:so through SQOOP only we can do that. Dont depend on there answers they are fake sites showing certification test dumps

Comment: Sorry, but I put the EDIT in the wrong place earlier. I fixed it - The MapReduce example was an explanation why the 2nd question's answer is B. Can you please consider it again? Thank you.

Comment: @theexplorer: The statement itself is wrong right: Write a MapReduce job, with the web servers for mappers, and the Hadoop cluster nodes for reduces...webservers for mappers...mappers input will be a directory of files and reducer will process the intermediate data from mappers. how can reducers do Hadoop cluster nodes..there is no sense in that option . what we tell hadoop cluster is the entire setup of hadoop(includes nodes).reducers perform on key and list of values.

Answer (score 1):

1 is C. Sqoop is the way to go with ingest from a database into hdfs. It is built and optimized for this purpose.
2 is A. Similarly, collecting high volume weblogs in real time is a common Flume use case.